# Why does form get submitted after onsubmit return undefined?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I only tested in Chrome and Firefox.

```
<form method="POST" action="post.php?action=newthread&fid=170" onsubmit="return validate(this)">
    <!--some other input elements-->
    <input type="submit">
</form>

<script>
    function validate(form) {
        // do some check, if failed, returns false
        // does not have return statement, returns undefined in Chrome and Firefox
    }
</script>
```

It turns out if the function `validate` returns `undefined`, the form still gets submitted. But if it returns `false`, the form will not get submitted which is expected. I thought `undefined` would stop the form from submitting. Can someone explain this behaviour? Thank you.

Comment: can you not just make sure it has a return value?

Comment: [The return Statement](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-12.9) @Popnoodles

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Javascript uses exact comparisons (like `===` rather then `==`) when testing the return value of the event handler. The only return value that prevents the default action is `false`. Any other return value, including `undefined`, allows the default action to take place.